# How to split array based on property value without changing order of keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an array like :

```
var test_array = [
{
"test_name":"vna",
"header_region":"vna_results",
"header_name":"larm",
"value_title":"area"},
{
"test_name":"vna",
"header_region":"vna_results",
"header_name":"larm",
"value_title":"area"},
{
"test_name":"lma",
"header_region":"lma_results",
"header_name":"larm",
"value_title":"area"},
{
"test_name":"lma",
"header_region":"lma_results",
"header_name":"larm",
"value_title":"area"},
{
"test_name":"uni",
"header_region":"uni_results",
"header_name":"larm",
"value_title":"area"},
{
"test_name":"uni",
"header_region":"uni_results",
"header_name":"larm",
"value_title":"area"}
]
```

and i want to split this into objects based on property value:header_name

```
{
"vna_results":[
{
"test_name":"vna",
"header_region":"vna_results",
"header_name":"larm",
"value_title":"area"
},
{
"test_name":"vna",
"header_region":"vna_results",
"header_name":"larm",
"value_title":"area"
}
],
"lma_results":[
{
"test_name":"vna",
"header_region":"lma_results",
"header_name":"larm",
"value_title":"area"
},
{
"test_name":"vna",
"header_region":"lma_results",
"header_name":"larm",
"value_title":"area"
}
],
"uni_results":[
{
"test_name":"vna",
"header_region":"uni_results",
"header_name":"larm",
"value_title":"area"
},
{
"test_name":"vna",
"header_region":"uni_results",
"header_name":"larm",
"value_title":"area"
}
]
}
```

i am using below function to achieve this:

```
function groupBy(arr, property) {
        return arr.reduce(function(memo, x) {
            if (!memo[x[property]]) { memo[x[property]] = []; }
            memo[x[property]].push(x);
            return memo;
        }, {});
 }



 var splitted =  groupBy(test_array, 'header_region');

but the output result changed the order of keys: lma_results first then uni and then vna..
lmi_results:{...},
uni_results:{...},
vna_results:{...},

expected order- same as in array 
i don't want to change the order. how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: The order of keys in an object is never guaranteed. If you need this guarantee then you will have to change the data structure to use an array of values, as only then is the order retained

Comment: You can sort them by value but that will either result in ascending or decending order not the actual order. As suggested by @RoryMcCrossan you should you array instead of object.

Comment: If you need to keep ordering, consider using something other than an object. Or maybe use an extra array to hold the order of the keys?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test_array = [{
    "test_name": "vna",
    "header_region": "vna_results",
    "header_name": "larm",
    "value_title": "area"
  },
  {
    "test_name": "vna",
    "header_region": "vna_results",
    "header_name": "larm",
    "value_title": "area"
  },
  {
    "test_name": "lma",
    "header_region": "lma_results",
    "header_name": "larm",
    "value_title": "area"
  },
  {
    "test_name": "lma",
    "header_region": "lma_results",
    "header_name": "larm",
    "value_title": "area"
  },
  {
    "test_name": "uni",
    "header_region": "uni_results",
    "header_name": "larm",
    "value_title": "area"
  },
  {
    "test_name": "uni",
    "header_region": "uni_results",
    "header_name": "larm",
    "value_title": "area"
  }
]

const result = test_array.reduce((acc, x) => ({
...acc,
[x.header_region]: [...(acc[x.header_region] || []), x]
}), {});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer??

Comment: Ok, but kindly add explanation it would be helpful for me.

Comment: result changed the order of array

Comment: the keys in the output are consistent to what you want... from what I can see..